# Vector in the initializer list of a class

Tags: c++

I have a learner list/vector defined in one `.hpp` file like this:

`std::vector<DecisionTree> learners_;`.

Now in the constructor, this is used like this:

```
Bagging::Bagging(const DataReader& dr, const int ensembleSize, uint seed) : 
  dr_(dr), 
  ensembleSize_(ensembleSize),
  learners_({}) {
  random_number_generator.seed(seed);
  buildBag();
}
```

What is happening in the constructor?

Does the program try to fill only two instances within that vector where the first one is a random number and second one is a call to a function? But how does it work because `buildBag` returns a decision tree but the second argument returns an integer and we declared it as a vector of decisionTrees?

Why are there curly brackets `({})`?

As I have always programmed in java and python, this is hard to grasp and it does not come from any book but from the code example.

Comment: The brace after the vector initialization is the beginning of the Bagging constructor body. Nothing to do with the vector, it just happens to be the last thing initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dr_(dr), ensembleSize_(ensembleSize), learners_({})` : These are used to initialize the object variables of `Bagging` Class to the specific values provided when the constructor is called.

`({})` means that the `std::vector<DecisionTree> learners_` is initialized to just an empty vector through an *initializer list* (it's a C++11 thing).

```
{
  random_number_generator.seed(seed);
  buildBag();
}
```

Finally, these statements are the body of the constructor of `Bagging` Class. Plain commands that are executed upon creation of an object.

Comment: There is no need to initialize a vector with an empty initializer_list. The result is still an empty vector, same as if the vector were allowed to be implicitly default constructed instead